# Google Analytics: 1 custom report for all sites in the same account

Tags: google-analytics

I'm fairly new to GA, so please bear with me...

I know how to create a custom report for one site. But is there a way I can create a custom report for all the sites, where all sites would be individually listed.

Here you see that I have more then one site under the same account:

[image: Google Analytics Screenshots]

This is what I'm doing at the moment, by hand:

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Tks all!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: It's about programming. It's about using the Google Analytics API to consolidate requests to multiple Views into a single report. And @Blexy below calls it right. Google's `magic script` lets you build a Google Doc in which you can compose a sheet with a single view of metrics from all accounts, using a mix of JS and Google Spreadsheet coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [supermetrics](http://supermetrics.com/product/supermetrics-for-googledocs/) or google's own [magic script](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics/fefimfimnhjjkomigakinmjileehfopp) to pull in data from multiple accounts into Google Spreadsheets.